# How can I get the date & time from the network provider?

Tags: android, datetime, time

Is there a way to get the date & time from the network provider programmatically? Possibly in the same manner in which we get the location from the network provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You may need to use a custom NITZ or NTP Library**

- http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d5ce3bcfe17e272b?pli=1

> So just a heads up that Android uses NITZ events provided by a carrier
>   to properly set the system date and time.  Android also falls-back to
>   network NTP automatically when no cellular network is available.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ
>
> The time provided by currentTimeMillis() will typically be the best
>   available time, and it's what all of the services on the device use,
>   like Calendar and Alarm Clock.

However

> However the NTP API isn't somewhere that Java code can access, which
>   means we're back to using an existing Java NTP/SNTP client library if
>   we want an accurate time regardless of whether we are on a network
>   that is NITZ capable.

**Java NTP library**

You can find a naive implementation of a Java NTP Library from

- [support.ntp.org](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient)

Comment: why it's not provided by android itself,as it's the basic need of developer it their application,anyone can make the Application fool by changing the time if we use Calendar

Answer (score -3):

The Answer is YES 
I tried the following code to get the time from network provider
use loc.getTime() for that

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        latitude.setText(""+loc.getLatitude());
        longitude.setText(""+loc.getLongitude());
        time.setText(""+loc.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact time of the last know location? And it's not from the carrier, but from the GPS (although the latter is more accurate)

Comment: It could be from either, there is a LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and a LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: this does not get the time, it displays the time of the moment when the last location was fetched. what if you are immobile and not moving? your location will not change and thus you will not get the time updated?