# Preventing user from manipulating the time that will be stored in the local database of Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to make an employee attendance app where the users (employees) could punch in when they come to the office. The details they punch-in will be sent to the server. The major focus in on the time.

I am trying to implement offline functionality as well. (If the app doesn't detect internet connectivity, the punched-in record will be stored on the local db (SQLite) , and once it does, push the record from the db (and clear it) onto the server.

I tried capturing the time using the *GregorianCalendar* class but the time values seem to be vulnerable to user manipulation. (Especially Scenario A)

**Scenario A**

A user could turn internet connectivity off,  turn *Automatic Data & Time* off, manually set the time and then open the app to punch in.

*Example:* Mr. X comes to office at 8.45AM, turns airplane mode on, manually sets the device time (say 8.30AM) and then punches-in the record. The time value that he sets gets entered in the db instead of the actual time he came in.

How do I prevent this from happening?

**Scenario B**

A user could just edit the local db values manually (rooted phones). [I know this is inevitable but any suggestions to make his harder?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario A:
Solution 1:  only accept values when there is an internet connection:

```
private boolean haveInternet()
{
     ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Solution 2: ping your server for the timeDate.

Solution 3: register a broadcast receiver for the timechange event and disable the app until you can ping your server (taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20766107/2540578)

Scenario B: encrypt the data. There are multiple solutions to do this, but it depends on what you are using (sqlite, realm, greendao etc)

Comment: The offline functionality is the very reason why we're doing the app, so that's a must. So, adding to _Solution 3_, anything more you could think of?