# Does the Android OS maintain an Internal Clock?

Tags: android, clock

What I mean is, is there a clock in the system that is maintained separately from the clock which is set by the user? I'm curious regarding writing apps that do some function once per day, and how the programmer keeps the user from just setting back the clock and spamming the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the answer in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw). Looks like thats exactly what you are looking for

Comment: ah! the Network Provider. Good link... Thank you. I wonder how you would handle it if the phone was in airport mode or out of signal range.