# Measure long elapsed time (with reboots) on Android

Tags: android, time, reboot, elapsedtime, time-measurement

I need to measure long elapsed time on Android and there may be device reboots in between.

From what I've understand, `System.nanoTime()` is resetted every time the device reboot, and `System.currentTimeMillis()` is unreliable because user can change it.

The only solution that I came up with is to listen to `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` and `BOOT_COMPLETED`, use `System.currentTimeMillisec()` to calculate the elapsed time (user can't change clock time while the device is off, hopefully :) ) and add it to the last `System.nanoTime()` I had before shutting down.

I honestly don't like this solution because it's very expensive (I need to listen to 2 broadcast events) and inaccurate, but I couldn't figure out any other way to do this.

Any ideas? Also a native solution would be good for me.

Comment: I don't think there's a better way. At a minimum you will have to listen to two system broadcasts, BOOT_COMPLETED and ACTION_SHUTDOWN. You could optimize the remaining stuff around these two. But this is the minimum you have to do, i believe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic that should be the time behind those two. Android devices will self-adjust the `System.currentTimeMillisec()` based on external time sources (possibly NTP, GSM, GPS, ?) - no user intervention required and probably at boot (i.e. before `BOOT_COMPLETED`). You could use an external time service as well but that needs network access.

Comment: A user who is willing to override the platform clocks to defeat you is quite likely a user who can just intercept/patch whatever system calls you are using to read them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around the user changing time by using an internet time server to get the times when you check.  There are a couple of ways to do this.

- Get it via NTP server

  - [How to get current time from internet in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android)
  - [How can I get the "network" time, (from the "Automatic" setting called "Use network-provided values"), NOT the time on the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw)
- Get it via HTTP header

  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses ( see `Date` header )

If you simply persist this value then the user can do nothing to mess up your calculation.

Comment: Your idea is for sure correct, but I was searching for something that doesn't add any overhead, so using NTP is not a suitable solution for me.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there's no solution on-phone that is guaranteed to be the correct time unless you can somehow get a timestamp from the carrier.  As far as I see, that's not exposed.  As you may know the radio is basically a separate operating system.