# Android system time

Tags: android

in my application i need to get current Date and time, every time the user inputs data with it.

I know i can use System.currentTimeMillis(), but it can give me wrong time(because it gives system time, witch can be edited by user)
So i see the only way is to call server for current time, when the user makes data input. but i am not sure that internet connection is always awailable.

Is there any way to get current time (not system time) in android, without using internet connection?

Comment: This may sound like a daunting task !!!

Comment: maybe my answer will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31990307/3345366

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want system time you need some other source then.
There are a few possibilities that I know:

1. Get it from web - Internet needed
2. Get it from router - enabled wifi needed ([NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol))
3. Get it from GPS - GPS fix needed

All of these aren't very helpful I believe. I don't think you can find a way of getting current time without connecting so something externally.
In my opinion you should use system time and assume it's set correctly. When it's not your application shouldn't crash and should gently know user that he has wrong content because of wrong dates ...

Comment: Ok. so, i see, internet or GPS is the only way to get REAL current time. But what if user enters some place without any connections(underground, or building). I have an idea, that i can calculate current time by using my last successfull time update(from GPS or internet) and calculate elapsed time.

Comment: Possibly phone restart and your idea will fail. Think about trusting system time, why can't you do that?

Comment: i have tricky users) they have tasks for every day, but they modify system date, and "simulate" every-day work in just 1 day

Comment: When that's the case you could register some broadcast receiver for Internet Availability, get current time from server and save it with current SystemClock.uptimeMillis() in your preferences. On app start you can get stored values and current uptime to calculate actual time. Your users would need to have Internet enabled only once per reboot (event without starting your app). Possibly you would also need to clear those values on phone reboot. I don't think anyone will be able to trick this :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no way to get the current system time without the timezone.

A good approach would be getting the current system time first

```
long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And then getting the correct TimeZone to handle it

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
```

Comment: time zone is not a problem. the problem is thet my users can modify system data from android time settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
    long dateInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    String dateString = sdf.format(new Date(dateInMillis));
```

Use `dateString` as your variable which contains current date time as timestamp.

Comment: time zone is not a problem. the problem is that my users can modify system data from android time settings.

Comment: you want datetime using Asia/Kolkata timezone ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I googled about your topic, and i got logic solution but not tested:

**" Use The network-provided values "**, in the android phone settings, it;a as shown in the picture bellow:

[image]

The screen I show is **DateTimeSettings**. The checkbox "Use network-provided values" is associated to the shared preference String ***KEY_AUTO_TIME*** = "***auto_time***"; and also to **Settings.System.AUTO_TIME**

This settings is observed by an observed called **mAutoTimeObserver** in the 2 network ServiceStateTrackers:  **GsmServiceStateTracker** and **CdmaServiceStateTracker**.

Both implementations call a method called **revertToNitz**() when the settings becomes true. Apparently **NITZ** is the equivalent of **NTP** in the carrier world.

Bottom line: You can set the time to the value provided by the carrier thanks to **revertToNitz()**. Unfortunately, I haven't found a mechanism to get the network time. If you really need to do this, I'm afraid, you'll have to copy these **ServiceStateTrackers** implementations, catch the intent raised by the framework (I suppose), and add a **getter** to **mSavedTime**.

For more informations, i suggest you to check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw)

Comment: oww !! so as i told you before 'This may sound like a daunting task'

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with `scheduleAtFixedRate` to send you "clock ticks".  If the user initiates an event and the number of accumulated "clock ticks" since the last event doesn't match the time change on the system clock, you're being lied to.

You don't need to know the correct time.  You need to know the correct interval.  This can be done with any periodic source, even a local one.  (Timekeeping is two jobs: a metronome and a labeler for the intervals of the metronome.  You don't want the system's labels because they can be made to lie, but the metronome ticks on even if the labels are changed.)

I'd recommend a relatively slow tick rate (<= 1 tick per minute) and rather sloppy comparisons (within 2%, maybe) since the various clocks may not be all that accurate.