# Android how to get device's time not timezone time

Tags: java, android, time, timezone

My case is: user set timezone to `UTC+5`, for example, and then turn off time and timezone sync. When he goes to `UTC+4` timezone, he just set the time back to an hour, without touching timezone.

So the `Calendar.getInstance()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` return the time for `UTC+5`, for example, 14:00, but the device shows 13:00.

How can I get the device time(13:00) or difference between device time and current timezone time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that I could find, kept here in this [post](https://pristalovpavel.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/how-to-get-the-real-device-time-with-wrong-time-zone/).

**Summary**: it is impossible to obtain the necessary time difference with no additional queries to the server and / or receiving your own coordinates (which may not always be available).

This also applies to canceled daylight time: some devices still believes that in the summer time zone of Moscow is `GMT+4`, other part knows that it's `GMT+3`. And you can not locally sync these devices locally, in general.