# Get time according to current location/current time zone

Tags: java, android

I want to get the current time according to current time zone even I change my current time zone from my phone and change my time but still, I should be able to get the current time and date. How to get that?

```
Time currentTime = new Time();
currentTime.setToNow();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();

Date date = cal.getTime();
strDate = date.toString();
```

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to get local time

```
   public static Date getLocalDate(String timeStamp) {
        int index = timeStamp.indexOf("+");
        String dateTime;
        if (index > 0) {
            timeStamp = timeStamp.substring(0, index);
        }

        int indexGMT = timeStamp.indexOf("GMT");
        int indexPlus = timeStamp.indexOf("+");
        if (indexGMT > 0) {
            dateTime = timeStamp.substring(0, indexGMT);
        } else if (indexPlus > 0) {
            dateTime = timeStamp.substring(0, indexPlus);
        } else {
            dateTime = timeStamp;
        }
        SimpleDateFormat sdfgmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdfgmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdfmad = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdfmad.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date gmtDate;
        Date localDate = null;
        try {
            gmtDate = sdfgmt.parse(dateTime);
            localDate = sdfmad.parse(sdfmad.format(gmtDate));
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
        return localDate;
    }
```

To get current UNIX timestamp, you can use the below code

```
 long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

Comment: But user can be of any country not only of India and time stamp should also be generated automatically of current location

Comment: @Aditya UNIX timestamp is always unique regardless of the location(Timezone).

Comment: @Aditya For the reference, check this answer by RobP https://stackoverflow.com/a/23062640/3948854

Comment: i tried your code @Rishabh but it didn't work as i got the timestamp as --- 1565588955 and passed it in the function and got error

Comment: @Aditya does it worked? you will have to parse it as String before parsing to the function.

Comment: can you give me full example?

Answer (score 1):

try this

KOTLIN

```
fun getDateTimeString( ): String {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.timeZone= TimeZone.getDefault()
            calendar.timeInMillis = Date().time
            return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.time)

    }
```

JAVA

```
private String getDateTimeString(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Get time form Google : [How to get current time from Google for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789922/how-to-get-current-time-from-google-for-android)

```
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            String dateStr = response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue();
            //Here I do something with the Date String
            System.out.println(dateStr);

        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: can you please give me java code not kotlin @Lakhwinder

Comment: i changed my time and date from settings and then it gave me the changed date and time not today's date and time @Lakhwinder

Comment: Obviously, it will give you the time basis on your device's current time, what do you actually required?

Comment: I want to get the current time according to current time zone even I change my current time zone from my phone and change my time  or date but still, I should be able to get the current time and date. How to get that?

Comment: is that be helpful, if i let you know that time is not set to Automatic, then you can ask the user to set time to automatic and it will give you the correct time always

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

Use modern *java.time* classes.

Get the current default time zone of the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

Or ask the user.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

Get the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of that region.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Extract the time of day.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

If you want an update, if you want to gather the current moment again using whatever zone might now be current, simply repeat the steps above. The *java.time* objects are immutable, and do not auto-update; you must ask for  new objects with fresh data.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systmDefault() ).toLocalDate()
```