# Capturing an event when the Android system time is updated from the network

Tags: android, systemtime

If a device has been configured with `Settings->Date & time->Automatic date & time` it will update it's system time when the device connects to the network (and the network can provide a time).

Is there an event that I can subscribe to, so that I know if and when this occurs?

Comment: What about `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` Action

Comment: The accepted answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw might help

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK you're correct, propose it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are broadcasts for those events. `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` and `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED`

ACTION docs at `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED`