# Get real device TimeZone on Android even if setDefault was called

Tags: java, android, timezone

Say there's a component in the app that overrides the default time zone with `TimeZone.setDefault()`, and let's assume that's OK!
*(I see it's a bad practice, but for the sake of this question, let's just go with it.)*

In some places very limited cases I still need the actual device's time zone, but `TimeZone.getDefault()` will provide the overridden value.

**Is there a way to query the device's actual time zone (set in Android settings/provided by network) without asking Java's `TimeZone#getDefault`?**

Comment: Can you not just cache the original timezone provided to the JVM in which your app was run?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw/14720918#14720918), this might be usefull

Answer (score 0):

You could use internet, use this API request (from lat long):

http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?formatted=true&lat=44&lng=11&username=demo

it returns:

```
 {
  "sunrise": "2017-02-15 07:15",
  "lng": 11,
  "countryCode": "IT",
  "gmtOffset": 1,
  "rawOffset": 1,
  "sunset": "2017-02-15 17:45",
  "timezoneId": "Europe/Rome",
  "dstOffset": 2,
  "countryName": "Italy",
  "time": "2017-02-15 19:27",
  "lat": 44
}
```

Comment: That doesn't obey the user preference. If you go to settings, you can actually change your time zone to something else other than what's at your physical location.