# How to get network provided date and time without internet connection?

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker, networkmanager

I want to use **network provided date and time** in my android application **even if network date and time is disable** in device setting and there is **no internet connectivity**. Is there any possibility or any solution?

---

I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw?rq=1) but I didn't get perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String s1= android.provider.Settings.System.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
           android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME);
    if (s1.contentEquals("0")) {
        android.provider.Settings.System.putString(
                this.getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, "1");
    }
    Date d1= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Log.e("finalvalue", d1.toString());
```

Don't forget to give **permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Its not possible to set permission.WRITE_SETTINGS in latest OS(tested with 7.0) . Only system app can use these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Check permission if ok get time.

```
     LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Location location=locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(location!=null){
        long time = location.getTime();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I already tried your solution but I getting different time like this **06-07 15:23:03.548 1734-1734/com.abc.example E/myDate11: myDate:Thu Jun 07 15:22:57 GMT+05:30 2007**

Comment: This time may not be completely accurate.

Comment: this actually return the time at which the location received... IF GPS is off for a long time, last know location will be different and corresponding time will aslo differ