# How do I run a counter when the app is closed or sent to the background?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm working on a game where ants collect food and I'm trying to get the amount of time that the user was offline so I can calculate the amount of food the ants should have had collected. I have tried to run a timertask and looper to count the time in onDstroy but it didn't work. I'm open to some other ideas.

```
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(left,right);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    offlineTime = prefs.getInt("offline",0);
    onTime = prefs.getInt("ont",0);
    totalTime = prefs.getInt("total",0);

    offlineTime = totalTime - onTime;

    intent = new Intent(BackgroundSoundService.this, LandingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("offline", offlineTime);
    startActivity(intent);
    offlineTime = 0;
    totalTime = 0;
    onTime = 0;
}
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    stopMuOn = true;
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            totalTime++;
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("total",totalTime);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }, 100); // Millisecond 1000 = 1 sec

}
public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}

public void onStop() {

}
public void onPause() {
    player.pause();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("ont",onTime);
    editor.apply();
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: There is a lot of missing context to your code.  Only from the tag that shows at the bottom did I know you were talking about Android (because I got here via the Java subject, and I'm not familiar with Android classes).  Showing import statements and  mentioning a game engine if you are using one, would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to set a timer when your app is closed. And you cannot set a timer because it will get destroyed when app closes.

You simply need to get the system time like this

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Store this current system time in shared preferences when user exits.
And when the user comes back online get the savedTime from preferences and compare with freshly fetched currentTime.

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long elapsedTime = currentTime - savedTime;
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked, the only problem is that the player can change his phone time and pretend he was offline for a longer period for goods.

Comment: Yes this is a common loophole which players exploit in many games. To prevent this you need to use Network Time instead of System Time. Read this link for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw