# Time Stamp in Android

Tags: android

I am working in an Android application where i have to capture and save data locally with current Date & Time, later which will sent to the web server.

Now the issue is if user changed the Date & Time of Handset, application stores wrong data.

I need to get current Date & Time from **Network Provider or some other way** in **LOW OR NO Network** area, because in proper network i can get **Web Server** Date & Time, so i have to work for low or no Network area.

Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: Well if you have no network, how would the device know the "correct" time? The only thing it has is its own date...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157184/get-datetime-from-network-provider) on how to programatically get network-provided values in your code. This should solve the problem provided the web server also uses network-provided date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Use local time stamping which is updated periodically.
Sync the timer on network connection then keep a check if the user has manipulated the time, the stamps will be invalid.
Idea is similar to web certificates.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use GPS time, will be off by a bit but better than nothing and available most of the time.